# catkin use msg error: no matching function for call to ros::NodeHandle::subscribe

Tags: ros, catkin, msg, rosmsg, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to use a msg defined in a rosbuild package in catkin.

I include the .h file of this msg from the rosbuild package directly, and I can create the object successfully. i.e. `tld_msgs::BoundingBox newMsg;` but when I want to subscribe to a topic that publish this msg I got a compile error

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [20], int, int (&)(const BoundingBox&))’
```

I create the subscriber like this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/tld_tracked_object", 20, callback);
```

and the callback function:

```
int callback(const tld_msgs::BoundingBox &data) { }
```

Can anyone figure out my mistake?

Thanks

===============================

I copied the msg file into the catkin workspace with the same package name and compiled successfully.

But I got the same error here.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [20], int, int (&)(const BoundingBox&))’
```

I think it should be the problem in my callback function. and I need to modify this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/tld_tracked_object", 20, callback);
```

I googled and find I need to modify it like:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/tld_tracked_object", 20, tld_msgs::BoundingBox callback);
```

but it says `error: ‘callback’ is not a member of ‘tld_msgs’`

since there is only a msg folder in my `tld_msgs` folder, I have no idea how to add this in my msg file...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189129/catkin-use-msg-error:-no-matching-function-for-call-to-ros::nodehandle::subscribe/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for everyone's help.

I finally found where the problem is.

It is possible in catakin workspace to use the msg defined in rosbuild package, just include the header file generated by the original msg file is okay.

And the error occurred because I want the function return an `int` value.

I checked some working package and found I should not do that, the callback function should be a `void` function.

Then it compiles with no error after I change it to

```
void callback(const tld_msgs::BoundingBox &data) { }
```

---

Originally posted by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) with karma: 279 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) on 2014-08-07**:
You can also use `void callback(tld_msgs::BoundingBox::ConstPtr &data) { }` which is a more ROSy way of doing this.

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-08-07**:
thanks for the suggestion. I will try to be more ROSy  :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on rosbuild packages from catkin packages is not possible.

You can either catkinize your message package or use rosbuild for the package you're trying to build.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-08-06**:
hi @ahendrix, I updated my question. Could you help me with the new problem? thanks

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-08-06**:
I think @Christian Dondrup's answer is correct, you need to drop the `&`. However @ahendrix is also correct that depending on a rosbuild package with catkin is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The compile error should just result from a missing `&` infront of `callback` to make it a function pointer.

Try

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/tld_tracked_object", 20, &callback);
```

No garuentee that the whole programme will work afterwards but it should at least compile.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1